# Не могу SSH в Raspberry Pi Zero

Tags: windows, ssh, usb, raspberry-pi, драйвер

Записываю Raspbian на micro-SD, добавляю в config "dtoverlay=dwc2", а в cmdline: "modules-load=dwc2,g_ether" и создаю пустой файл "ssh" без расширения. Пытаюсь подключиться с помощью Putty к raspberrypi.local выдаёт ошибку "Unable to open connection to raspberrypi.local Host doesnt exist"
-когда вставляю micro-SD в ноутбук, то ssh файла там уже нету
-Bonjour установлен
-первый запуск малинки был без модификации config и cmdline и ssh Файла, потом заново записал Raspbian, модифицировал файлы и все равно та же ошибка.
-при первом запуске это было RNDIS устройство, а сейчас малинка определяется как Устройство с последовательным интерфейсом USB COM4, думаю проблема в этом, но Windows банально не даёт поменять драйвера на другие, RNDIS просто нету в списке

Пишу сюда, бо уже не знаю что делать, помогите пожалуйста

Answer (score 0):

И спустя 2 минуты как написал вопросы, сразу же нашёл ответ на него

https://forum.moddevices.com/t/rndis-driver-for-windows-10/299/8

Описан в этой теме, там же ссылка на RNDIS драйвера. Просто установить их из папки в диспетчере устройств.